Indexing a list in Lambda calculus
I have tried to implement a list indexing function in lambda calculus and for some reason it is not working. Would anyone be able to point out to me what I am doing wrong? Assuming standard church encoding for numerals. Thank you.
nil  = \c.\n.n
cons = \h.\t.\c.\n.c h (t c n)
identity = \x. x
Example
list = cons 4 (cons 2 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))

should become list = \c.\n. c 4 (c 2 (c 2 ( c 3 (n))))

index = \l. \n. true (n(false l identity 0))
index list 2

should become true (2(false 4 (2 (2 (3 (0))))) = true (false(false(4 (2 (2 (3 (0))))) = true (false (2 (2 (3 (0))) = true (2 (3 (0)) = 2


What do you mean by indexing a list? I can’t tell from the example alone

@confusedcius access an element at given index n

Recall that a Church numeral $n$ is $λf.λx. f^n x$. When given arguments, it applies $f$ to $x$ $n$ times.
So to index a list, we can apply the tail function to the list n-1 times, then get the head of the list. Assuming the list is 0-indexed, we can just use the index i to apply the tail i times.
$$index := λl.\ λi.\ head\ (i\ tail\ l)$$
For example,
$$list := λc.λn.\ c\ 2\ (c\ 5\ (c\ 3\ n)) = [2;5;3]\\
index\ list\ 1 \rightarrow head\ (1\ tail\ list)\\
\rightarrow head\ (1\ tail\ (λc.λn.\ c\ 2\ (c\ 5\ (c\ 3\ n)))) \\ 
\rightarrow head\ (tail\ (λc.λn.\ c\ 2\ (c\ 5\ (c\ 3\ n)))) \\
\rightarrow head\ (λc.λn.\ c\ 5\ (c\ 3\ n)) \\
\rightarrow 5 \\\\$$
Both $head$ and $tail$ returns $nil$ when the list is $nil$, so this function returns $nil$ if the index is out of bound.
In your attempt, note that true is $λa.λb. a$, so $true\ (2\ (3\ (0)) = λb. (2\ (3\ (0))$, and not $2$ (and there are similar errors in other steps).

But what are the head and tail functions?

@Fraser Oh I assumed they’d be given since they’re usually more important than other list functions. Head returns the first element, tail returns the list without the first element

But how do you implement those?
second = \x. false x
tail = \l. \c. \n. second (l c n)

@Fraser head is pretty straightforward but how to implement tail is not obvious. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding (list encoding section, right fold)

Btw your implementation doesn’t work for the same reason. You seem to be making the same mistake again. You should write out an example, and make sure you write down parentheses
